# Find $X_s(f)$ of a sampled continuous signal

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, transform, digital

I've been trying to find the transform of the following signal, but have not been successful, any help would be greatly appreciated:

> Find $X_s(f)$ of the following signal the "mathematical DAC"
>   generates:
>
> $$x_s(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^nx(nT_s)\delta(t-nT_s)$$

Comment: Try using $ {\left( -1 \right)}^{n} = \cos \left( \pi n \right) $ and see what happens.

Comment: @Sak that read like homework a lot, so I assume you want to at least cite the institute/person asking this?

Answer (score 0):

As this feels extremely much like homework, let's give you pointers and let you derive the final answer:

1. The Fourier transform is a linear operation, which means

   1. the transform of a sum is the sum of the transforms of the single parts, and
   2. constants can be "extracted" from each transform and just scale it.
2. Summation is associative and hence, you can first look at all even and then at all odd terms isolatedly
3. There's the convolution theorem that tells you something about the transform of $x(t) \cdot \delta(t)$,
4. the transform of $\delta(t)$ is especially simply done manually, and the transform of $\delta(t-\tau)$ can easily be found manually, too.